# Suggestion reference for Calkin Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I am interested in Calkin Algebras, I want to do a self-study, but I don't know what would be a good source to start with

Does anyone have a good recommendation of books//lectures/resources/etc.?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at the references given at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin_algebra)?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite:

S.R. Caradus, W.E. Pfaffenberger and B. Yood:

Calkin Algebras and Algebras of Operators on Banach Spaces

(Marcel Dekker, New York, 1974)